# can't find bin folder in my minecraft folder!

Tags: minecraft

I've installed minecraft a long time ago and currently running on the 1.3.2 version. The Ubuntu's version I'm currently using is 12.04.

I've decided to install some mods on my minecraft, did a lot of research, and found out that the mod folder should be placed in the bin folder in minecraft. But here comes the problem, I don't have a bin folder in my minecraft.jar folder!

(I've also installed a new skin without any problems onto the 1.3.2 version of minecraft)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: the bin folder is located inside the `.minecraft` folder in your home directory. To see it, press ctrl+h inside nautilus when your in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

I can access my Minecraft bin directory by going to `~/.minecraft/bin/`

---

Although this isn't Ubuntu specific, may I recommend that you try out [MagicLauncher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/939149-launcher-magic-launcher-100-mods-options-news/).  This allows you to install and enable/disable Minecraft mods really easily.

Once you run it click on Setup. You will be presented with this dialog:

[image: MagicLauncher Setup Dialog]

Then to add a mod click Add and select the zip of the mod you want to install. Really simple!